# Difference between after departure cancellation and no show

Tags: air-travel, tickets, jet-airways

In the fare rules for a flight I found that there is a 200 AED charge for a cancel and refund after departure, and 400 AED for no show. How does this work/what are the refund rules here if I miss the flight?

1. ticket price - 400 (no-show) - 200(cancel/refund)
2. ticket price - 400 (max of noshow and cancel)
3. ticket price - 200 (only cancellation fee)

In case of 2 or 3, is there a scenario where a post departure cancellation fee applies, but not a no show fee?

The specific flight from where I picked this up is 9W 531 on 10th Jan 2016, however a generic answer would be ideal

```
CANCELLATIONS



 BEFORE DEPARTURE

   CHARGE AED 200 FOR CANCEL/REFUND.

     NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.

      FULLY UNUTILIZED - ABOVE CHARGE WILL APPLY

      .....

      WAIVED FOR DEATH OF PASSENGER OR IMMEDIATE FAMILY

      MEMBER.

      .....



AFTER DEPARTURE

   CHARGE AED 200 FOR CANCEL/REFUND.

     NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.

      PARTIALLY UTILIZED - ABOVE CHARGE WILL APPLY

      .....

      FOR REFUND-

      ON SECTORS WHERE FIRST CLASS/PREMIERE SERVICE IS

      NOT OFFERED/AVAILABLE AT THE TIME OF TICKETING

      PASSENGERS MAY BE BOOKED IN THE NEXT LOWER CABIN.

      NO REFUND WILL BE PERMITTED FOR CLASS DIFFERENCE

      IN SUCH CASES.

      .....

      WAIVED FOR DEATH OF PASSENGER OR IMMEDIATE FAMILY

      MEMBER.

      .....



CHANGES/CANCELLATIONS



 CHARGE AED 400 FOR NO-SHOW.

     NOTE - TEXT BELOW NOT VALIDATED FOR AUTOPRICING.

      INFANT DISCOUNT APPLICABLE ON PENALTIES.

      .....

      IF A NO SHOW TICKET IS PROCESSED FOR ANY CHANGES/

      REFUND THEN THE PENALTIES FOR CHANGES/REFUND

      WILL BE APPLICABLE IN ADDITION TO THE NO SHOW

      PENALTY.
```

Comment: It reads like option 1. It's worth noting that the no-show penalty alone doesn't really matter if it's less than no-show + cancellation, as they won't be automtically sending you money back - only if you call up to cancel.

Comment: It's likely to depend on the airline.  Since you mention a 9W flight I am adding the [tag:jet-airways] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term "departure" in this context refers to the departure of the **first** flight on the ticket.

Thus "before departure" is before you have flown any segments on the ticket.  "After departure" is after you've flown any segment.

So say you have a ticket that has a flight on the 3rd of December, and a return flight on the 7th of December.  If on the 1st of December you decide to change any of the details of the flight, the "before departure" rules will apply.  If instead on the 4th of December you decide to change your return flight, the "after departure" rules will apply.

In this case the change fee is the same for both before and after departure, but it's likely the rest of the conditions are different (eg, the way that the new fares would be calculated)

"No-show" is not related to the above, and simply means that you fail to show up for one of the legs of your flight.  It doesn't matter if this is the first leg, the last, or anything in the middle.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is notification.

If you call / contact them and cancel your flight(s) then the penalty would be AED 200 if you notify them before you take any of the ticketed flights or AED 200 if you cancel after you started (ie cancel your return flight and come home another way).  For this particular fare the penalties are the same, but that is not always the case, hence why they list them separately.

If you do not show up for your flight and did not contact them in advance to let them know you are not flying, then it is considered a No Show, in which case the AED 400 penalty would be applied to any refund you might be eligible for.

If you have another flight / ticket which is delayed causing you to miss the above referenced flight, it will still be considered a No Show, but the airline may take the situation into account and perhaps offer the lower penalty.

Answer (score 1):

You will pay one of the penalties (either the cancel or the no-show).  Which one depends on the situation.  You do not ever want to be a no-show.  Your ticket has unusually generous terms; most tickets today have a penalty if cancelled or changed, but are void (lose all value) if you no-show.

If you ever find yourself in a situation where you will not make a flight (e.g., stuck in traffic, flat tire, inbound flight delay, stuck at connecting airport), call the airline.  In many cases, you won't even be charged the change fee (especially if it's a situation out of your control) and you will be rebooked on a different flight.  The exception to calling ahead is if you are in the U.S. flying on a domestic airline and will arrive at the airport (via car or train, not another flight) too late to clear security and board.  In this situation, the phone agent is likely to charge you the change fee, so you are better off going to the airline ticket counter in the airport and hoping for treatment under the "flat tire" policy, under which an airport agent may rebook you on a different flight without charge.